# Smart Contracts that Swarm tokens for theft - Is this transaction fraudulant / Requires Sharing?

Tags: phishing

I have prveviously been a victim of Smart Contract Malware which was sent to my wallet without permission.

Can someone who understands coding make a quick comment on exactly what this transaction is and is it safe ?  If not what is it and how does one protect against this form of attack.
Thanks for any advice here 
Transaction below and data

```
0x0865954c3a6d0d6cf6cb057e8ff200d1ed55723fc1b310434119b143acc8ee91
TimeStamp:
3 days 23 hrs ago (Mar-02-2019 11:30:49 AM +UTC)
From:
0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8 
To:
Contract 0x2f6321db2461f68676f42f396330a4dc4a8f49df 
Tokens Transfered:
(175 ERC-20 Transfers found)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x3cdc146acff8edac37feb8ffb73246ca597828c6For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd9a23c2247cbc7f87f42f4acf1ee590689692438For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xffb46c97ab3d8f6d82e2f7ac14f84be99ff6a74cFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xcd6214699ef36b6b39e2514086b08bdf1dbb5634For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4f772cde4aa30f2a7cd5ef17154c79660269a300For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd7bc5ec6a64ec88193d89b8564085cc363c30e80For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xfc0188b6344b7d077c76bc30bbca3d4075f7a859For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb37651e15898411ac898e3c1a109fbe59204e81fFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xf9d8bb330ffeba43036f037c82d8fca1d5834c77For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x3231a497281c088262daa5bda2a0bea3c78f19ccFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x0be5e981647ea827f7b184e74306106d9fc3a461For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x5a75924af830a9d95c54b6e8520b652c52377a4dFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x7a017366f14aaf27a2c68969f45629208a68e1f6For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xbc1de018e4784fbe4cd2586f2f5798ddcbe2b54eFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x9a8c11b0fb1ab67dc632c032d470d862a8fcb56dFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x2eef759e60a1d81c35d982acfe99b8f38b72eca5For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4c9c998847adf0ac2ded098678da6d4552b5bb0dFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x9ed53dc133e44890777a9848a12de98da7327ae9For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x19b1fa410bc3c1938b27fd175402a4bdce645053For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x0b8fea04316355de3f912fc5f7aa2a32235e8986For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x546cccdb2166a83b080610fe37053e41b95e2cc8For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x93e7a5b9fa8e34f58ee8d4b4562b627c04ead99bFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xef32adf80ddc9f9ef6d2c2dd9ea0057cf9a903a3For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x269709f9d1bc090b33a0f9152b8c1b0846e09a29For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x351313f49476ed58214d07bb87162527be34978eFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4178ff48704adbd0f0efc1f5db72a572f25abb9bFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xcdaa280a9942cbbbe233047496550c4fd4e02336For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb80285b999933c73d208bad057f807b84384dc0dFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa76b4d96e4a1a81497a79678fcef8c5b008c150eFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd7a39b56ce405e054a0837db295557e307168c84For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x40b95671c37116bf41f0d2e68bd93ad10d25502eFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xdfcee0e4e371e02d7744e9eca3fa6269e116b1c9For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x2e49816e7ae0efd7a59c61f452d81c03d77dcabdFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x782c534dea5176264bbad4f3f94a6609a852442eFor 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4a8773de41543bc041e820d4a79c74f6dae85c11For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x7dd71b315f12de87c1f136a179db8cc144b58295For 1,000 ($1.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xdbb15bc8316abd0b57f3d7f9d5606a061ea11246For 970 ($1.74)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x5b367be9bfd87391aca778abca4105a7a8c70616For 963.46 ($1.73)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xc20a8ba883de677baee83dd67afd28eb894a4ec6For 920.74 ($1.65)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x0fffbefabc0e688900e44d9246b2d6fbffb58b0cFor 910.55 ($1.63)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xe91d7b771bddf83a134cb01e1789d2a905d73356For 900 ($1.61)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x31f0ce524d08c0723feed586d0d6931824d46d2aFor 900 ($1.61)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6dcc131c0cbd1602b39a75fb3cdaf86e860be529For 899.48 ($1.61)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x10c88fe2475cfacacc95ec29f7192638fa3f888eFor 864.7 ($1.55)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6e34eab2248def983b38decdf14a69ba0838d92dFor 852.42 ($1.53)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb75f39175b51b34bff648605b18d7e08a5e658a9For 850 ($1.52)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xfbcce1228708d8b478ecf5a51c364253df75577fFor 850 ($1.52)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x0dd51d1483d4e92e858ea45bee7148d2d32c388eFor 819.85 ($1.47)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xe26bdb9e61070b5d0816b1f027eb2d105b675093For 801.75 ($1.44)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x18f247ae07c8d82bdbcdb756d0bf20f9e5b7c243For 800 ($1.43)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb6ab04d0ffddf467c8805c6f9609a2a640542d91For 787.04 ($1.41)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xbfe0291035d67ac4b11332059fbd76e84b85c18dFor 772.47 ($1.38)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xbe66edc50d69dca4f50c3679738b2637dddf4600For 770.89 ($1.38)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4985885f15665bbc3105cbfa95fa0a3e8b2ad1abFor 746 ($1.34)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6ae631012668ad44ac2131af0c28424385f2e867For 721.65 ($1.29)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x35fc6da1c8c863622ec21db3992fea2c329e8477For 691 ($1.24)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa9f24c5b1b30e66b10ca4d72d41166e778260e01For 676.88 ($1.21)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb3833a0cb0c53ad89bb12eeffe78ede05936c035For 660 ($1.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xc868ae4f79b8e6780f40216408751401e3b46740For 657.33 ($1.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6a0a0265457e4bf464607d3f5654d149bd46bc87For 655.34 ($1.17)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x209bd67f299a782d8d6c8c715c04c7e8fe790c3dFor 650 ($1.16)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd9a187baaef2842ad2b093324d7cbd0686311b9eFor 633.73 ($1.14)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa5956fc7566c49a3da85c92738cc349969c09c5fFor 603.01 ($1.08)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xfc346690666b1f3e0b8fa729f94cce64969ed074For 601.25 ($1.08)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4ac3b6633a0fac6269fbde9b3e651d02ace1e87eFor 594.97 ($1.07)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xdfc38911f6e0bfdd0472f6f68d83e8a0115768b2For 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb384234e5ba56e9cd3519b5221077d48d05dd809For 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa18d4e229fec4967b617eb45efac52de7a0709f1For 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6204974bea4bdb28ab7c7972419672c3d04c0a6dFor 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x83937f6d6178145589113a51214d7f17983199c0For 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xec261a28dbc20382bae80ac826b42a20acfd1c72For 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6f371a162f7d13cbd40813fac00b95866336da9cFor 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x31c530474e1fdeb12a15e963eb95c939b12a6e3fFor 590 ($1.06)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xcb3da011a27febec705845c3b2b1aa3e7f001719For 565.96 ($1.01)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xdd3b9186da521abe707b48b8f805fb3cd5eee0eeFor 564.83 ($1.01)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xeb3b9bac44743149bc91d0cd74ccf2a62dbfdf39For 560 ($1.00)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa8cd35d961e255c87e58ed3fe9396e090716aeccFor 536 ($0.96)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x3d30bbdbddb4fd9dbcd9e0d718ee97b68b8c95d5For 535 ($0.96)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4760a84fcdd0802b78fc1596981579ff537656c8For 533.03 ($0.96)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x09060168c66c203785482dc27e5603d0973f8055For 522.24 ($0.94)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa3a11f9b6fb05463437a75beddac979471282cd5For 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x1dc4fccb982a89b303dd4204fa05f78dbe4c4666For 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x63819aebc9d9d85d41fdc707043333ad482c3819For 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6060ac5a42b19f70e21bd54d39b03183e2554b1aFor 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x522e62e0499bc25d0290fb1c56ff4994e1700ba0For 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xbae67e4c807c8b15cd366ff3551d6d194070043aFor 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xe06548cbd2fc02b74efe7575680dbf46b16cb508For 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xef25fbd4f2a20b8e3dbc515a2e2e01b0d6ca2340For 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x90f5560a548b62dfdc87ecba254ac8f31327f63aFor 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x8a8f230ddb835adda5a20463af6c8788062626f1For 500 ($0.90)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x082370726584bb0f63fa95fcf7426d78ad496341For 480.36 ($0.86)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x8eb2d72fcac7ee1d4668f7c169afb87f9092da7cFor 463.44 ($0.83)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa6cdd8f360360a0c3a6f59c80dbb72d3c172161cFor 439.93 ($0.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x2f004df8862f599884e24ef592ee1cc3403d73dfFor 439.54 ($0.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x46d2f6cee3175aa986f262d3731fcf2521f728a7For 439 ($0.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xf6f6079c4ab943bd888dac4d10a10ec4dcd09502For 438.22 ($0.79)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa5cc679a3528956e8032df4f03756c077c1ee3f4For 424.02 ($0.76)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x844f1e1e0614e43c0163c65eae435f5a759243c3For 402.02 ($0.72)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x534fa198d62cc396c58f6e220488dbb143f8f6f6For 400 ($0.72)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x1d824f955a1d6f55a4ca4754d299ebddef1fc6b4For 400 ($0.72)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xbe438e4d6fb032430b2b0fba1b73d6884cf05cecFor 376.02 ($0.67)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb3397a6feedff2b9fce9ca1086cb1bdd617c16bfFor 372.5 ($0.67)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x2757f7bd5401f80b80eea47d9a86ce70a7403494For 372 ($0.67)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x1d19fd2ed78f0312ec043ec381651770c0bdeb6fFor 365.45 ($0.65)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xc655dd67e2f3c6621ae8b21c795da1bc6e50411dFor 365.45 ($0.65)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x10e3dcfe3eeacd8a5857ab9d82c5c43344d003d3For 350 ($0.63)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa943fa32e58e55cad6bde57826f13649f7ddfc88For 346.07 ($0.62)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x04a1fc7e46f469caa312fe4973c12e90a9be67f4For 315.15 ($0.56)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x2798573774b2f6514d917cfad5d0d17dac9cf435For 311 ($0.56)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xcc38479a95531c28a8934fcb89a08ce798b4df9cFor 300.27 ($0.54)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd72b01bca1c24fdd2977505e2f5888a0afe28a93For 299.59 ($0.54)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x7df618c193bffd172b2194a0b66f1c726f069d1eFor 297.49 ($0.53)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xc393c6b23cfa3a801c397e64d15eff464b0b6112For 291.39 ($0.52)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4eb4d57441e9c3d2df51e8e4af7cc4502366d555For 288.55 ($0.52)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xc3a1274b78fd6e66881154f9d10560cc237e36d7For 263.05 ($0.47)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x1c4664f6164504f9a58def53ac101fb6a3dad7c3For 260 ($0.47)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xaa4004480ff45e315eb5e2a2b36bc76e8a1a3f8fFor 260 ($0.47)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x833091e1478bcf097c389e52b0172e7d0da6c1ffFor 250 ($0.45)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x428359c7bd1440358abe8dda13efafbf737c8567For 250 ($0.45)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xe2a4a9019f047e46a77c14a8272b09053725a3c2For 238.51 ($0.43)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x0a24bde9d7618f9b745036fe0a7b57c7451ed724For 234.42 ($0.42)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x7255bb0af6e36b9880c1a0d588c43c9f20119dbfFor 219.01 ($0.39)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xc2ce2da9cf4f8509d62bfe211e2cf44c9f86cb7bFor 200 ($0.36)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x628e81069de8367d73436584dea49e181579d4a6For 200 ($0.36)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x38ac6155b3c9978d83b3b2354b63da2b43782f0aFor 200 ($0.36)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xe77e7e6ff3962bc52002389540cb6d6499e8379aFor 200 ($0.36)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x6cf2d940dc70b56eda0b5b0d1b50894412f469a9For 198.09 ($0.35)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x26c7b96bcbd50cdb695dcb69d171003fd5551f2dFor 189.25 ($0.34)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x7c30f8a9554b90e205b010e44ef8b7f0073f8fe5For 183.35 ($0.33)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xbd9d8b5a76ca0143d6f5729e88758fe811888e5fFor 180 ($0.32)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x5343c1385f9398ccb448b6eab9d80fd698564da1For 151 ($0.27)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb7737b656e54c5a5337f2c29fa62cf423a0fa461For 146.35 ($0.26)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x865caf042bda841fc49016c19aad4a8129f8761cFor 131 ($0.23)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xf6bfcd9d3a8cd98c1e33f0637467b6878f1640efFor 123.45 ($0.22)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x74a8614f6ee6870dba25b7b8c5b0cee648d553f9For 118.95 ($0.21)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd72bb3efb285e14b192b7c175975a5850dd6439dFor 107 ($0.19)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x9f36c0d60331a1d64d61571dda3d1429e1af642eFor 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x1b52652596e949ee0218ba1d6116417aa3dc20e0For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x3b4edc178c1d68c7acad4552bbf7863be58b1c1fFor 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x5cf090727545d5e550b0d3923e5b3ee53d551742For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x9cb7d205e3991b58bb47063a6614b4f4346e6d2bFor 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x330fa4442836b587c3075c2dd74bda452a23141aFor 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x1ab14b7cd35e06d4a6e05bb97c64497068410e9eFor 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x91a9700266af9f1fd0e207ccb35a899f0dca00a7For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x093f6de9abab047d45fe528a1c7d33fc95d92512For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4759cf04ddada1100012a349b14fdc294fae5879For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x9281f8e0873f2d0419efd48399ab99cd253577f5For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xf6cd65a20e907e22698af4060d1b0993b2dd4005For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x8e6609d61943ffc396f1b4a77f73b19e55e6bbafFor 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x97afc6f3003d893cb41cbea317f7e307ae75a747For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x9ce2334e8b1dcccb40bcd0e353270cc444169976For 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x89519dd058bbd7af43c1a2b9c18ab6ac4520fe3aFor 100 ($0.18)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x1812f90b047abca3a5e32f8d66162762695f7fd1For 97.15 ($0.17)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x157962d83558ef65891caf571ef9fc52aff89f3bFor 93.09 ($0.17)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd24f55c94a28aa9bdc3da49c6810d5e397175cd5For 91.16 ($0.16)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xde20b94ab1df3a778719b09f75b3b937d0a55a3fFor 87 ($0.16)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xc177113ef1b56bc6110a5440768b79b9e068be73For 80 ($0.14)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xa2941a1409f785811066a035dfe39d9aec29721bFor 77 ($0.14)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4ac8db4a89378d8573ab51bcd3c89f924258d33dFor 73.53 ($0.13)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x4f9914bc884fd842c9cff70be4fc4fb5525cb679For 73 ($0.13)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xf901a956bbdfa5202318f4b855283969ef34f507For 70 ($0.13)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xe67174da63c77273e92e4cb50355a91ac161506aFor 70 ($0.13)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xd5c40242369761d51be729f3774cfacf1b1aadb5For 66.45 ($0.12)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xcf5539abce7f3d046e7e532f970faf459d929d48For 65.83 ($0.12)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x21aaa6c835ca9c606d444fd5787ffbefc88c1c20For 60 ($0.11)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xbfe16b84fa1e9dadb061e9c3369b6d40a9c6732cFor 60 ($0.11)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xca2720117959f3fd5c2e61635dfaef2721a74d2aFor 60 ($0.11)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xb261ec53a1b69133318fe27c083c2d35512c208dFor 55.45 ($0.10)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x0368ffc98a5e08be4bd8c2a66976b188c1606d9aFor 54.65 ($0.10)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x76aaae01ab35df6e4640a220c8bf0112038ac194For 50 ($0.09)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x7311c79d77bb97b35aa53f842a15194fdbc57399For 50 ($0.09)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0xfc126025e19871bc3c1db3eabf3c99cba206ce8eFor 50 ($0.09)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x8df4c8d91c908d207a7cd065bf92eef486633c97For 50 ($0.09)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x5847773ab6701e15f612db7717bd3ab6b9e63816For 50 ($0.09)  ERC-20 (PCL)
From 0x5b96b1f07151010c9b05faddc7bfb24b8569c3e8To 0x167589bf67752ccb079151fac71504d8bf8ac196For 50 ($0.09)  ERC-20 (PCL)
Scroll for more
```

Comment: This question lacks enough context, does not clarify what the author wants to know and has some data without explaining where it is from. It is very difficult to answer to this question. I suggest you edit the question and try to explain your question in more detail.

Comment: I was hoping that someone could view the transaction first and comment on what its doing. As per " I have prveviously been a victim of Smart Contract Malware which was sent to my wallet without permission."
"Can someone who understands coding make a quick comment on exactly what this transaction is and is it safe ?"

Comment: What I am asking is best explained above and i am not sure what further explanation i can provide.

Comment: I will further include two transactions of same token PCL which i lasted traded some time ago as shown following    142 days ago and i have not traded any further PC:

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x491c252f472180e137b7ea74bd474e5786d5a2c4f950f8ba787cf50f432350d9

Comment: Today in same wallet i noticed another transaction for same amount of PCL which i suspect looks similar to one which milked my ethereum away some time back in small amounts.  I am not a solidity or smart contract programmer but have basic investigative skills across many other areas. I also dislike being stung and wish to hamper those involved in the black hat trade.  Mext is the trade from four days ago i did not make or sign and note the same token amount deposited. 0x491c252f472180e137b7ea74bd474e5786d5a2c4f950f8ba787cf50f432350d9

Comment: What wallet ? I'm not sure understanding coding is related to your issue. This is just a list of transactions showing that 0x5b96b1f...To sent some tokens to the contrat but that's all, point us to what you find strange in this otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: I dont think you assessed the data very well because it shows a list of transactions made to wallet addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Is this just someone sending tokens to you? If so, there's nothing you can do. Erc-20 tokens don't actually live in your wallet, it's the contract that holds values for each users balances. This is likely an airdrop, and it isn't malicious

Comment: Thamks for taking time to add this info - appreciated

Comment: If this solved your question you can accept the question so that other people know this is a solved issue